# Delegate error in swift 2

Tags: swift2

I'm having trouble passing data after run App.I'm pretty much trying to change a label from the previous view controller after selecting a table view cell
Could anyone help me go about there error?

> view controller

```
class AircraftSearch: UIViewController ,SendbackDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var Mabda: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var maghsad: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelcity: UILabel!


    var Airurl = NSURL()
    var ScrOrDstArray = [MabdaAndMaghsad]()
    var origin = [String]() // save mabda
    var purpose = [String]() // save maghsad
    var sendDataToTableview = [String]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GetPassCity()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func selectMabda(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendDataToTableview = origin
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectedCellSegue", sender: sender)


    }

    @IBAction func selectMaghsad(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendDataToTableview = purpose
        print(sendDataToTableview)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectedCellSegue", sender: sender)

    }


    func originAndpurpose() {
        let dataCity = ScrOrDstArray
        for i in dataCity{

            if i.SrcOrDst == true{
                origin.append(i.Name)
            }else{
                purpose.append(i.Name)
            }
        }
    }



    func GetPassCity(){
        let actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView        = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        actInd.center                           = self.view.center
        actInd.hidesWhenStopped                 = true
        actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle       = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(actInd)
        actInd.startAnimating()

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(Airurl){ ( data ,response ,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("A")
                print(error!)
            }else{

                do{
                    //readin data from Server
                    let posts   = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    //save data
                    for post in posts{
                        var postCity:MabdaAndMaghsad?
                        if  let  Id         = post["Id"]        as? Int     ,
                            let nameCity    = post["Name"]      as? String  ,
                            let SrcOrDst    = post["SrcOrDst"]  as? Bool
                        {
                            postCity    = MabdaAndMaghsad(ID: Id, Name: nameCity, SrcOrDst: SrcOrDst)
                        }
                        self.ScrOrDstArray.append(postCity!)

                    }

                    //===============

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                        actInd.stopAnimating()
                        self.originAndpurpose()
                       print(self.origin)
                        print("=======")
                     //   print(self.purpose)
                    }

                }catch let error as NSError{

                    print("B")
                    print(error)
                }
            }


            }.resume()

    }


    func sendNameToPreviousVC(SelectCity: String) {
        labelcity.text = SelectCity

    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SelectedCellSegue" {
            if let VC = segue.destinationViewController as? SelectedCity {

                VC.toTake = sendDataToTableview
                VC.delegate = self
            }
        }

    }

}
```

> and tableview Controller
>   import UIKit
>   protocol SendbackDelegate:class {
>       func sendNameToPreviousVC(City:String)
>   }

```
class SelectedCity: UITableViewController {
    var toTake = [String]()
    var selecteCity = String()
    weak var delegate: SendbackDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return toTake.count ?? 0

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? mAndMCell

        let nameCity = toTake[indexPath.row]
        print(nameCity)

        cell!.nameCityLabel.text = nameCity
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! mAndMCell!

        selecteCity = currentCell.nameCityLabel!.text as String!

        sendBackIdCity(selecteCity)
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)



    }
    func sendBackIdCity(name: String){
        self.delegate?.sendNameToPreviousVC(name)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "backCitySegue"{
            var VCOne = segue.destinationViewController as? AircraftSearch
                VCOne.delegate = self


        }
    }



}
```

error is line  `VCOne.delegate = self`

error = `Value of type 'AircraftSearch?' has no member 'delegate'`

Comment: Please do not change the core of your question, but consider accepting my answer for the one problem you had in the first place! Then google for your new problem since there are already plenty of solutions for that. If you end up not being able to solve it on your own come back and ask *post a new* question.

Comment: @luk2302 Coercing the OP into accepting your answer isn't cool either.

Comment: @trojanfoe it apparently answered his question, did it not? Since his program compiles, runs and throws a different error - what should be the correct response? (I rephrased it a bit, sry for way it sounded previously)

Comment: @luk2302 Yes you are right, but it's still not cool.

Comment: @trojanfoe okay, I should not have included the part about accepting my answer, right? The rest was okay?

Comment: Yup seems good to me.

Comment: No , luk2302 are right , and I made a mistake,Excuse me of @luk2302 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should probably be

```
self.delegate = VCOne
```

since `self` is the `SelectedCity` which has the `delegate` property and `VCOne` is of type `AircraftSearch` and therefore *is* a `SendbackDelegate`!

Comment: @Shadow no, that is a different issue. Please try to come up with a solution for that on your own. I reverted your edit to reflect the previous question.

Comment: when I change self.delegate = VCOne .this line fatal error:        labelcity!.text = SelectCity

Comment: @Shadow you may have not hooked up your IBOutlet connections correctly for that UILabel

Comment: No , it is connections correctly , and when print(SelectCity ) return data

Comment: @Shadow not `SelectCity` is the problem but `labelcity` seems to be `nil` - why is there a `!` anyway? In the code you posted in your question it is defined as `UILabel!`, therefore you do not need to unwrap it later in the process.

Comment: I didn't see you mean ؟